# How to say "the fish's home is the water"

Tags: translation

I was wondering if the following sentence and translation match up with each other:

```
鱼的家是水。


The fish's home is the water。
```

The sentence seems quite crude to me even though the point might get across. Does the sentence sound juvenile or awkward to a Chinese speaker? And is "家“ understood to be home, or can it be mixed up with family?

Comment: seems possible,also  水是鱼（类）的家 cf.iciba: The river is home to a fish and a crocodile.

河是鱼和鳄鱼的家

Comment: 家 here refers to 'world' as in ; 'Human's home is Earth' (Earth is human's world)

Comment: Any context? Maybe I would prefer 鱼的家在水里 here.

Answer (score 2):

yes, 鱼的家是水。is juvenile and awkward,

but still need associate specific context，

it's ok if in story of children，or just express thought，

in Chinese will say fish live in water

Answer (score 2):

from  your  question.  Two  possibles:
(1)  如鱼得水；
(2)  鱼水一家人。
Aforementioned  answer  are  quite  dufferent  in  Chinese  context.

(1)  Means  someone  come  across  the  most advantaged situation  which  is  favorite  for  his  career、 personal  objective or  something  like  that.
(2) Means  someone  has  very  good  relationship  with  others.  And  their relationship  are  just  like  Chinese  family  member.

The  precise  translation  needs  the  context.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are talking about 如鱼得水 ?

Comment: I doubt that is the case based on the sentence from the original post, but you could elaborate what 如鱼得水 means in addition to the question

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few expressions which can match fairly closely, depending on what you want:

1. 魚之依水 - Fish rely on the water; compare 鳥之依木 (birds rely on trees), 農之依田 (farmers rely on the field *[for sustenance]*)
2. 如魚得水 - Like a fish in the water; same meaning as English *in [somebody's] element*, implies some kind of advantage (rather than a *lifeline* like 1.)
3. 魚以水爲天 - Same as (1)
4. 魚以水為住處 - Literally, water is the residence of fish

Answer (score -1):

Just for your reference
鱼在水中生活
鱼生活在水中
鱼的家在水里
鱼水情